# Specifying factor variables

Tags: r

This is probably super trivial but I can't figure it out.
I was writing an R script that will clean/organize my data (which is still being collected) so that once data collection is done, I'll have everything already written.
I'm encountering a problem with factor variables. The race/ethnicity variable is stored as numeric: 1 = white, 2 = black, 3 = asian, 4 = hispanic, 5 = other.
Right now the five observations look like this:

```
race <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 2)
```

I would like to convert the race variable into factor, so I tried:

```
race.f <- factor(race, labels = c("white", "black", "asian", "hisp",
"native", "other"))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in factor(race, labels = c("white", "black", "asian", "hisp", 
"native",  : invalid 'labels'; length 6 should be 1 or 4
```

I'm guessing this is because I am saying there are 6 labels, but in my dataset there are only observations for 4 out of the 6 possible outcomes.
I'm sure this can be solved with the levels argument, but I can't figure out when/where to use it. I tried

```
race.f <- factor(race, levels = c("white", "black", "asian", "hisp", 
"native", "other"))
```

And it just created a bunch of NAs.
If I happen to collect data from at least one person of each of the 6 ethnicities, the code I posted above would work. However, there's no guarantee that that'll happen. How should I go about handling this when writing the script before the data is collected? I would like for it to handle all possible outcomes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `NA` because, `race` by default is not a `factor` and using it inside `factor()` as it is, causes NA since it's not able to find the specified levels in `race`. Therefore we must first match the values in `race` to their corresponding `races`

For this, we need to have a look-up vector like below :

```
vec <- c("white"=1, "black" = 2, "asian" = 3,"hispanic" = 4, "other" = 5)

set.seed(100)
race <- sample(1:5, 8, replace = T)
# [1] 2 2 3 1 3 3 5 2

race_new <- names(vec)[match(race, vec)] # match() returns the position where race matched with vec in vec
factor(race_new, levels = names(vec))
# [1] black black asian white asian asian other black
# Levels: white black asian hispanic other
```

---

@Imo's suggestion( more concise) :Or you could use the levels together with the labels argument to factor:

```
race.f <- factor(race, levels=1:6, labels = c("white", "black", "asian",
                                              "hisp", "native", "other"))
```

Comment: Or you could use the levels together with the labels argument to `factor`: `race.f <- factor(race, levels=1:6, labels = c("white", "black", "asian", "hisp", "native", "other"))`.

Comment: @lmo recommend posting as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`race` levels are integer, which you need to define for all labels when creating the factor:

```
race.f <- factor(race, 
                 levels = 1:6, # one for each label
                 labels = c("white", "black", "asian", 
                            "hisp", "native", "other"))
```